# Not all the output is redirected into file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to redirect all the stdout to a file, out.txt. But first commands's output display's on the terminal and the rest is fed to the file. I am not sure whats wrong in the piece of code below.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = file('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

os.system("date") #First command

cmd = ["ls", "-al"]
exe_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = exe_cmd.communicate()
print output #Second command

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
```

Comment: What do you observe, that leads you to the conclusion that `Not all the output is redirected into file`?

Comment: Why don't you just do `stdout=f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a file object to `sys.stdout` redirects python code that uses `sys.stdout` but doesn't redirect code that uses the underlying file descriptor.

```
os.system("date")
```

spawns a new process that uses the underlying file descriptor, so its not redirected.

```
exe_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = exe_cmd.communicate()
print output #Second command
```

spawns a new process with a pipe that is read by the parent process. `print` uses the parent `sys.stdout` so it is redirected.

A standard way to redirect is to hand the file object to one of the `subprocess` calls. The child writes directly to the file without parent interaction.

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    cmd = ["ls", "-al"]
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So this works again for the second command alone. So do I need to create 2 file separate files for each command? As "With open" closes the file prematurely before the os.system("date") could be redirected.

Comment: Avoid `os.system` if you can. `subprocess` makes file redirection easier. You can use `os,dup2` to change the underlying file descriptors, but its harder. If you want all command stdout and stderr to go to one file, open it once and do `subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` for all of them. As for `with open`, all that matters is the file descriptor when the command is spawned. In the case of `os.system` and `subprocess.call`, the parent waits until the child exits, so it makes no difference.